# PostgreSQL table --data-only dump taking more than double the size of table

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-12

I have a Postgresql DB with a total size of 1.7TB. Out of which 1.6TB is occupied by one table. The total disk space was 1.7TB so I am now out of Disk space.

I cannot run Vacuum on it, I tried truncating few tables and then used the available space to run Vacuum o the other tables and was able to get some space. But the problem is that I cannot run a Vacuum on the table which is occupying 99% of the space.

So I tried to take the backup so that I can truncate this table. The backup is running and the size of the backup has grown past 3TB and still growing.

I am new to PostgreSQL and have no idea how to handle this situation.

I have a temporary 4TB space that I am using to take the backup but I am afraid this backup is going to grow more than the available space.

Any help/guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: About [`vacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html): "_... extra space is not returned to the operating system ..._" To make your dump smaller use `--format` option with `c` or `d` key of the [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) utility

Comment: @Abelisto it took me 2 days to dump it this far. I am also tight on the time side. Any suggestions on how to get out of this situation without spending a lot more time?

Comment: The "brute-force" way: drop unused or rarely used indexes on this huge table to free some space.  Then you will have a time to analyze the situation and find the solution. BTW such questions should be asked [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Noted. Let me ask it there.

Comment: If it is on Linux there are possible tricks like compressing like each 1GB chunk of the output file separately and then "poking a hole" in it with "fallocate --punch-hole". Also if pg_dump of 2TB is taking 2 days then maybe your pg_dump process is too far away network wise from the database - it's better to run pg_dump as close as possible and then only copy the compressed output between networks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```sh
pg_dump -F c -Z 9 -f dumpfile -t largetable dbname
```

That will be slow, but compresses the dump as much as possible.

It is perfectly normal for a plain text dump to be larger than the table. For example, an `integer` occupies 4 bytes and a `timestamp` 8 bytes, but their textual representation can be bigger. Also, larger column values get compressed on disk.

Comment: IMO `pg_basebackup` is the fastest way for this particular case. Or just copying the stopped cluster as is (never tried this)

Comment: @Abelisto But that won't shrink the table, will it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe then how to restore this dump. Anything special to add with pg_restore ?

Comment: @FahadNisar No, `pg_restore` knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no option of adding more storage, then you could perhaps handle the situation with gradual migration of the rows into a new table. Consider partitioning the table if isn't partitioned already.

The best way to deal with your situation is to add a storage device, even temporarily.

Regarding the difference of size between your table and the backup, I can think of two possible reasons:

1. You're not computing the correct table size. Perhaps there is a lot of data in the toast table.
2. You have lots of binary data and are backing up to a textual case. If that is the case then each byte of binary data gets expanded to two hexadecimal characters.

Comment: Numbers, dates, timestamps also stored in its text representation in backup...

Comment: @jonathan When you say "Gradual migration of rows into new table" you mean creating a new table in the same DB or in another db ?